# How to find elements by class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble parsing HTML elements with "class" attribute using Beautifulsoup. The code looks like this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
mydivs = soup.findAll('div')
for div in mydivs: 
    if (div["class"] == "stylelistrow"):
        print div
```

I get an error on the same line "after" the script finishes.

```
File "./beautifulcoding.py", line 130, in getlanguage
  if (div["class"] == "stylelistrow"):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 599, in __getitem__
   return self._getAttrMap()[key]
KeyError: 'class'
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1060, accepted):

You can refine your search to only find those divs with a given class using BS3:

```py
mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "stylelistrow"})
```

Comment: @Klaus- what if I want to use findAll instead?

Comment: This only works for exact matches. `<.. class="stylelistrow">` matches but not `<.. class="stylelistrow button">`.

Comment: @Wernight were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @pyCthon See answer for @jmunsch, BS now supports `class_` which works properly.

Comment: @pyCthon see my answer below for how to solve multiple class names with BS3

Comment: _class Will only match the exact class string if you have multiple classes. In that case you can use: `soup.select("p.stylelistrow.another")` which would match `<p class="stylelistrow another yetAnother">` for example

Comment: @Wernight Currently using BS4 (4.7.1) and `soup.find_all("div", {"class": "stylelistrow"})` works for both exact `<.. class="stylelistrow">` and contains `<.. class="stylelistrow button">` matches.

Comment: I want to find all div with a specific class inside a specific div, and not in other divs. How do I achieve it ?

Answer (score 441):

From the documentation:

[As of Beautiful Soup 4.1.2, you can search by CSS class using the keyword argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) `class_`:

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
```

Which in this case would be:

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="stylelistrow")
```

It would also work for:

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="stylelistrowone stylelistrowtwo")
```

Comment: You can use lists too: `soup.find_all("a", ["stylelistrowone", "stylelistrow"])` It's safer if you don't have many classes.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's both more correct and concise than the alternatives.

Comment: Supplement to @NunoAndré's answer for BeautifulSoup 3: `soup.findAll("a", {'class':['stylelistrowone', 'stylelistrow']})`.

Comment: So in bs4, class is replaced by class_? Why would i need SoupStrainer then if I could refine the search easy?

Comment: When would I use the 'dic way' and not the `=`, see @Klaus answer?

Comment: @Timo my guess would be that you can use the dict way when you're searching for an attribute other than class, so maybe something like `{'data-item': ['1']}`  ex. `<a data-item="1" />`

Comment: To extend your example , it would be then ('a',{'data-item': ['1']}). I will try this with the = (your answer), maybe will also work.

Comment: One thing to note should be, when you give `class_="class_1 class2"` it matches "exact string", so even `"class_2 class_1"` won't match. To search with multiple classes (all required), you should use selectors `soup.select('div.class_1.class_2')` this matches both `"class_1 class_2"` and `"class_2 class_1"`.

Answer (score 82):

Update: 2016
In the latest version of beautifulsoup, the method 'findAll' has been renamed to 
'find_all'. [Link to official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

[image: List of method names changed]

Hence the answer will be

```
soup.find_all("html_element", class_="your_class_name")
```

Answer (score 59):

CSS selectors

**single class first match**

```
soup.select_one('.stylelistrow')
```

**list of matches**

```
soup.select('.stylelistrow')
```

**compound class (i.e. AND another class)**

```
soup.select_one('.stylelistrow.otherclassname')
soup.select('.stylelistrow.otherclassname')
```

Spaces in compound class names e.g. `class = stylelistrow otherclassname` are replaced with ".". You can continue to add classes.

**list of classes (OR - match whichever present)**

```
soup.select_one('.stylelistrow, .otherclassname')
soup.select('.stylelistrow, .otherclassname')
```

Class attribute whose values contains a string e.g. with "stylelistrow":

starts with "style":

```
[class^=style]
```

ends with "row"

```
[class$=row]
```

contains "list":

```
[class*=list]
```

The ^, $ and * are operators. Read more here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors`

If you wanted to exclude this class then, with anchor tag as an example, selecting anchor tags without this class:

```
a:not(.stylelistrow)
```

You can pass simple, compound and complex css selectors lists inside of :not() pseudo class. See `https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:not`

---

bs4 4.7.1 +

Specific class whose `innerText` contains a string

```
soup.select_one('.stylelistrow:contains("some string")')
soup.select('.stylelistrow:contains("some string")')
```

N.B.

[soupsieve 2.1.0 + Dec'2020 onwards](https://github.com/facelessuser/soupsieve/releases/tag/2.1.0)

> NEW: In order to avoid conflicts with future CSS specification
> changes, non-standard pseudo classes will now start with the :-soup-
> prefix. As a consequence, :contains() will now be known as
> :-soup-contains(), though for a time the deprecated form of
> :contains() will still be allowed with a warning that users should
> migrate over to :-soup-contains().
>
> NEW: Added new non-standard pseudo class :-soup-contains-own() which
> operates similar to :-soup-contains() except that it only looks at
> text nodes directly associated with the currently scoped element and
> not its descendants.

Specific class which has a certain child element e.g. `a` tag

```
soup.select_one('.stylelistrow:has(a)')
soup.select('.stylelistrow:has(a)')
```

Comment: This worked well for be where I was looking to find by just class and not by element type.

Answer (score 24):

Specific to BeautifulSoup 3:

```
soup.findAll('div',
             {'class': lambda x: x 
                       and 'stylelistrow' in x.split()
             }
            )
```

Will find all of these:

```
<div class="stylelistrow">
<div class="stylelistrow button">
<div class="button stylelistrow">
```

Comment: Why not re.search('.*stylelistrow.*', x) ?

Comment: because then stylelistrow2 will match.   Better comment is "why not use string.find() instead of re?"

Comment: `lambda x: 'stylelistrow' in x.split()` is simple and beautiful

Comment: And I hate regexes.  Thank you!  (updating answer)  | keeping the 'x and' to test for None

Comment: "keeping the 'x and' to test for None"
I have found this for a long time

Answer (score 19):

A straight forward way would be :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
for each_div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'stylelist'}):
    print each_div
```

Make sure you take of the casing of **findAll**, its not **findall**

Comment: This only works for exact matches. `<.. class="stylelistrow">` matches but not `<.. class="stylelistrow button">`.

Answer (score 17):

Use `class_=` If you want to find element(s) **without stating the HTML tag**.

For single element:

```py
soup.find(class_='my-class-name')
```

For multiple elements:

```py
soup.find_all(class_='my-class-name')
```

Answer (score 15):

> ## How to find elements by class
>
> I'm having trouble parsing html elements with "class" attribute using Beautifulsoup.

You can easily find by one class, but if you want to find by the intersection of two classes, it's a little more difficult,

From the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) (emphasis added):

> If you want to search for tags that **match two or more** CSS classes, you should use a CSS selector:
>
> ```
> css_soup.select("p.strikeout.body")
> # [<p class="body strikeout"></p>]
> ```

To be clear, this selects only the p tags that are both strikeout and body class.

To find for the intersection of *any* in a set of classes (not the intersection, but the union), you can give a list to the `class_` keyword argument (as of 4.1.2):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
class_list = ["stylelistrow"] # can add any other classes to this list.
# will find any divs with any names in class_list:
mydivs = soup.find_all('div', class_=class_list)
```

Also note that findAll has been renamed from the camelCase to the more Pythonic `find_all`.

Answer (score 11):

As of BeautifulSoup 4+ ,

If you have a single class name , you can just pass the class name as parameter like :

```
mydivs = soup.find_all('div', 'class_name')
```

Or if you have more than one class names , just pass the list of class names as parameter like :

```
mydivs = soup.find_all('div', ['class1', 'class2'])
```

Answer (score 4):

the following worked for me

```
a_tag = soup.find_all("div",class_='full tabpublist')
```

Answer (score 4):

**single**

```
soup.find("form",{"class":"c-login__form"})
```

**multiple**

```
res=soup.find_all("input")
for each in res:
    print(each)
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me to access the class attribute (on beautifulsoup 4, contrary to what the documentation says). The KeyError comes a list being returned not a dictionary.

```
for hit in soup.findAll(name='span'):
    print hit.contents[1]['class']
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers did not work for me.

In other answers the `findAll` is being used on the soup object itself, but I needed a way to do a find by class name on objects inside a specific element extracted from the object I obtained after doing `findAll`.

If you are trying to do a search inside nested HTML elements to get objects by class name, try below -

```
# parse html
page_soup = soup(web_page.read(), "html.parser")

# filter out items matching class name
all_songs = page_soup.findAll("li", "song_item")

# traverse through all_songs
for song in all_songs:

    # get text out of span element matching class 'song_name'
    # doing a 'find' by class name within a specific song element taken out of 'all_songs' collection
    song.find("span", "song_name").text
```

Points to note:

1. I'm not explicitly defining the search to be on 'class' attribute `findAll("li", {"class": "song_item"})`, since it's the only attribute I'm searching on and it will by default search for class attribute if you don't exclusively tell which attribute you want to find on.
2. When you do a `findAll` or `find`, the resulting object is of class `bs4.element.ResultSet` which is a subclass of `list`. You can utilize all methods of `ResultSet`, inside any number of nested elements (as long as they are of type `ResultSet`) to do a find or find all.
3. My BS4 version - 4.9.1, Python version - 3.8.1

Answer (score 3):

Concerning @Wernight's comment on the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5041056/3731467) about partial matching...

You can partially match:

- `<div class="stylelistrow">` and
- `<div class="stylelistrow button">`

with [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho):

```
from gazpacho import Soup

my_divs = soup.find("div", {"class": "stylelistrow"}, partial=True)
```

Both will be captured and returned as a list of `Soup` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively we can use lxml, it support xpath and very fast!

```
from lxml import html, etree 

attr = html.fromstring(html_text)#passing the raw html
handles = attr.xpath('//div[@class="stylelistrow"]')#xpath exresssion to find that specific class

for each in handles:
    print(etree.tostring(each))#printing the html as string
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the div has a class attribute first, like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
mydivs = soup.findAll('div')
for div in mydivs:
    if "class" in div:
        if (div["class"]=="stylelistrow"):
            print div
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I guess your approach was right, but 4th line doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Ah I thought div worked like a dictionary, I'm not really familiar with Beautiful Soup so it was just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
for div in mydivs:
    try:
        clazz = div["class"]
    except KeyError:
        clazz = ""
    if (clazz == "stylelistrow"):
        print div
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
mydivs = soup.findAll('div')
for div in mydivs: 
    if (div.find(class_ == "stylelistrow"):
        print div
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'totalcount'})
```

replace 'totalcount' with your class name and 'span' with tag you are looking for. Also, if your class contains multiple names with space, just choose one and use.

P.S. This finds the first element with given criteria. If you want to find all elements then replace 'find' with 'find_all'.

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sdata)
mydivs = soup.select('div.stylelistrow')
print(len(mydivs))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your contribution. While this may be a correct answer, could you please add an explanation to help readers understand what new information your answer contributes? Using `soup.select()` has been mentioned in several other answers, so we need more than just code here.