# extracting information from an element of html file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to extract 402 from the following string. I am using beautiful soup .

```
<span class="bla bla bla"> <span class="ba1 ba1">  </span>402.00</span>
```

I tried using `strip()` but the element `bs4.element.resultset` doesnt allow this.

Please suggest as to how can I do it ??

any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Find the inner span and get the [`next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find('span', class_='bla').find('span', class_='ba1').next_sibling
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = '<span class="bla bla bla"> <span class="ba1 ba1">  </span>402.00</span>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find('span', class_='bla').find('span', class_='ba1').next_sibling
u'402.00'
```

Comment: for the element soup I am getting an error ---AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'.

Comment: @ayushbiyani well, you've provided the HTML code and the solution I've provided works for it. Provide the real HTML you are parsing (relevant part including `span` tags and the desired data). Thanks.

Comment: @ayush biyani, maybe you use a former versions of BeautifulSoup that didn't handle that easily the 'class' attribute, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/handling-class-attribute-in-beautifulsoup

Comment: BTW, you could get a quicker result with soup.find('span', class_='bla').getText()

Comment: @sebdelsol really good point about the version of `BeautifulSoup`. I bet this is it.

Comment: <span class="bld lrg red"> <span class="currencyINR">  </span>402.00</span>

Comment: d.find("span",{"class" : "bld lrg red"}).find("span",{"class" : "currencyINR"}).next_sibling
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-ca379f0269c5>", line 1, in <module>
    d.find("span",{"class" : "bld lrg red"}).find("span",{"class" : "currencyINR"}).next_sibling

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'