# findAll returning empty for html

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm using the `BeautifulSoup` module to parse an html file that I want to extract certain information from. Specifically game scores and team names.

However, when I use the `findAll` function, it continually returns empty for a string that is certainly within the html. If someone can explain what I am doing wrong it will be greatly appreciated. See code below.

```
import urllib
import bs4
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/scores?season=2017&date=2017-05-09'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"wisbb_teams"})
print(len(container))
```

Comment: That literal, `wisbb_teams`, doesn't seem to appear in the HTML for `my_url` at all.

Comment: Any luck with the scraping?

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax your using is the old version of `BeautifulSoup`, try instead something like **`find_all`** snake_case (see the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# ...
page_html = uClient.read()
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
list_of_divs = page_soup.find_all("div", class_="wisbb_name")
print(len(list_of_divs))
```

The older API used CamelCase, but bs4 uses snake_case

Also, **notice** that `find_all` takes can take a `class_` parameter to find by **class**.

See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471317/4443226, for some more info

Also, make sure you're looking for the correct classname! I don't see the class you're looking for, but rather these:

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you! Can i Ask how you were able to find the potential classes containg wisbb? Also, at least when I inspect the element on the page, such a class exists. Do you know why this would be the case? The information I want is nested within many classes within the html, is that potentially why I cannot find it?

Comment: I got that image just from using the firefox inspection console, and searching for that string wisbb :) I don't see any wisb_teams