# soup.findAll returning empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, findall

I am trying to scrape with soup and am obtaining an empty set when I call findAll

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url='https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplayView?catalogId=10123&langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=70KutR16JmLgr7Ka%2F385RFXrzDpOkSqx%2FRC3DnlU09%2BYcw0pR5cfIfC0kOlQywiD%2BTEe7ppq8ENXglbpqA8sDUtif1h3ZjrEoQkV29%2B90iqljHi2gm2T%2BDZHH2%2FCNeKB%2BkVglbz%2BNx1bKsSfE5L6SVtckHxg%2FM%2F%2FVieWp8vgaJTan0k1WrPjCrVuDs5WnbRN#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10123&categoryId=&parent_category_rn=&top_category=&pageSize=60&orderBy=RELEVANCE&searchTerm=milk&beginIndex=0&hideFilters=true&categoryFacetId1='

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html,'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product"}) 
containers
```

I also got empty datasets from these articles:
 [findAll returning empty for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940822/findall-returning-empty-for-html)

and [BeautifulSoup find_all() returns no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141049/beautifulsoup-find-all-returns-no-data)

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: I think you just got unlucky. Look at the page source. You'll notice for "product" there is a rogue space after the name: `class="product "`, which means you are referencing a class that doesn't exist. If you do Ctr+F for `class="product"`, you'll find 0 results, but for `class="product "`, you'll find 54.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Use the snippet tool via [edit] to include html and for python code, insert, select code and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: noted. Removed pictures of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page content is loaded with javascript, so you can't just use `BeautifulSoup` to parse it. You have to use another module like `selenium` to simulate javacript execution.

Here is an exemple:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplayView?catalogId=10123&langId=44&storeId=10151&krypto=70KutR16JmLgr7Ka%2F385RFXrzDpOkSqx%2FRC3DnlU09%2BYcw0pR5cfIfC0kOlQywiD%2BTEe7ppq8ENXglbpqA8sDUtif1h3ZjrEoQkV29%2B90iqljHi2gm2T%2BDZHH2%2FCNeKB%2BkVglbz%2BNx1bKsSfE5L6SVtckHxg%2FM%2F%2FVieWp8vgaJTan0k1WrPjCrVuDs5WnbRN#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10123&categoryId=&parent_category_rn=&top_category=&pageSize=60&orderBy=RELEVANCE&searchTerm=milk&beginIndex=0&hideFilters=true&categoryFacetId1='

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page,'html.parser')

containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product"})
print(containers)
print(len(containers))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
<div class="product "> ...
...,
<div class="product hl-product hookLogic highlighted straplineRow" ...    
]

64
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am having issues installing selenium:  WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Hoping once I solve that, I can accept your answer

Comment: You can check here for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: selenium is a heavy feature. hard to deploy. os based and complicated. hope someone gave better answer