# Regex search product name and get price

Tags: c#, regex, web-scraping, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I have list of product names and i want to search a product name in following given URL and i need to fetch only price.
for example i want to search "Tommee Tippee Disposable Breast Pads - 1 x 50 Pack"
on this URL 
http://www.boots.ie/baby-child/babyfeeding/breastfeeding-pumps
if i got successfull match then how can i get price i.e. €8.49
through scraping.
this is one of the demo URL similarly i have list of URLs

Please help me to provide any example or Regular Expression to do this job

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code service. Show what you have tried and where in your code you got stuck. And direct your question to that specific problem.

Comment: Moreover, I'd suggest posting an extract of the data rather than a link to a website. You probably linked the website with good intentions, but it could be abused for advertising or malware propagation, which always makes me wary and less likely to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

A few sample code might help you kick off this project.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.boots.ie/baby-child/babyfeeding/breastfeeding-pumps'
soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html.parser')
product_name_regex = 'Tommee Tippee Disposable Breast Pads - 1 x 50 Pack'
product_tag = soup.find('div', text=re.compile(product_name_regex))
price_tag = product_tag.find_next('div', { "class" : "product_price" })
price = price_tag.text
```

This short code is trying to parse the html page first, and then extract the information from that page through finding tags using text/class name.

A few links that might help you:
[BeautifulSoup Doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
,
[How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5041008/4206154)

Comment: Hi @Flames
this is right answer. I think this lib is for Python but i need in c#. is there any lib available in c# or Java-script.

Comment: Thanks for giving me Idea Got Solution in HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @AdeelNazir No problem.