# Web scraping using Python Beautiful Soup - can't extract simple value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the value 'Netcare Ltd', but can't make it work.

```
<h1 class="secondary-header">
<span class='marketNameHeader'>Netcare Ltd</span>
<span class='diaryNoteAddButtonContainer'></span>
</h1>
```

I have tried the following (and various other options), but not sure where I am going wrong. Any ideas what I am missing?

```
name = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'marketNameHeader'}).text
```

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class

Comment: Is there an error, or is it not outputting the proper value, could you tell us what about this is wrong?

Comment: Also looking at the BS4 documentation, you will want to use the method `get_text()` as just doing `.text` does not seem to be referenced there.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill I get the following error message when running the code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.3.py", line 42, in <module>
    name = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'marketNameHeader'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @manjeetss If you have the error please edit your question to include it, also, as I mentioned, you should use the `get_text()` method as `.text` is not mentioned in the BS4 documentation.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill Thank you. I have tried the following, but still got the error:

name = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'marketNameHeader'}).get_text()

Error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.3.py", line 42, in <module>
    name = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'marketNameHeader'}).get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 0):

remove `attrs`, use `.find` to get first element and `.find_all` for all element

```
name = soup.find('span', { "class" : "marketNameHeader" })
print(name.text)
```

Comment: I have tried the code, but get the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IGIndexDataScrape_Daily_v0.4.py", line 50, in <module>
    print(name1.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Removed .text and then get the value 'None' printed, but not the actual value