# Find beautifulsoup classes in Python that contains part of a string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can't seem to find out how to search for classes that contains a specific string
i.e. searching for the class "Header" would return both the class "This-Header" and "Header-that".

Anyone got a workable solution to this?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389481/91757) to a related question.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass callables and regular expressions as the `class_` keyword argument:

```
import re

soup.find('a', class_=re.compile(r'Header'))
```

Or:

```
soup.find('a', class_=lambda c: 'Header' in c)
```

Both of these will match `<a class="Test-Headers"></a>`, so you'll have to adjust them if that's not behavior you want.