# Finding element with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css

```html
<div class="product-header-wrapper">
    <div class="prices-container">
        <p class="price price--large">£250.00</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```py3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.johnlewis.com/herman-miller-classic-aeron-office-chair/p230630306")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = soup.findAll(classmethod = 'price price--large')
print(element.text)


print(request.content)"
```

I am looking to print the price in my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: I keep getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute text.

Comment: no luck Waqas Bukhary tried all samples with no luck. Should I be going up a level on the class? Not sure why it would not take the class since it happens to be the only one on the page.