# How to use BeautifulSoup to find an href link with a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, request

```
<div data-pet-card="pet-card" class="pet-card">

    <a data-pet-card="pet-card-link" href="https://Link-I-Want.com" 
    class="pet-card__link">
```

I am used to scraping html with BS4 but I am not super familiar with html itself and haven't come across an href that also has a class and the `data-pet-card="pet-card-link"` thing. I tried:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

but it prints nothing, and gives no errors.

Anything is helpful, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: You don't need to care about the data attribute, just the class.

Comment: @Dominik No, not trying to find a class. Trying to get the href link, but it is surrounded by a class on the same line. Like I said I am familiar with BS4 and I would know how to find a simple class. Thank you

Comment: No, you're trying to find the `a` tag with the class "pet-card__link".

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, how would I go about doing that

Answer (score 6):

The attribute you put in the `find_all` call is the thing you have, not the thing you want to find. Here you have the class, so use that:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', class_="pet-card__link"):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

(Because `class` is a reserved word in Python, you need to use `class_` here.)

Comment: Since this still printed nothing, there must be a problem with my request. Here is what I do and what it prints when I say print(response.text): `https://pastebin.com/FbJVnQUV`

Comment: That response doesn't contain any "pet-" divs at all.

Comment: I know that is what I figured the problem is.. but when I go to that link and then Inspect a part of the page it shows up right there so I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IhfxTuz You can see the specific line highlighted and the link itself in this screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a.get_attribute_list('href')[0])
```

Please try this solution.

Comment: Unfortunately prints nothing still

Comment: Which version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup4

Comment: @DevinGP I mean which version of BeautifulSoup4.