# How to get a string from a tag with a specific class with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML code in a table like this:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td class="class1">data1<td/>
      <td class="class2">data2<td/>
      <td class="class3">data3<td/>
      <td class="class4">data4<td/>
      <td class="class5">data5<td/>
    </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I use beautiful soup to get the data/string with a specific class?
When I use `print(soup.body.td)` I just get the first result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Answer (score 0):

[Rextester](http://rextester.com/XOP7004)

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <tr>
      <td class="class1">data1<td/>
      <td class="class2">data2<td/>
      <td class="class3">data3<td/>
      <td class="class4">data4<td/>
      <td class="class5">data5<td/>
    </tr>
  </body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
results = soup.find("td", {"class" : "class1"})
print(results.text)
```

Comment: Probably want `.find_all` since using class

Comment: If you use .find_all you are returned a different object type and cannot use the .text to return text inbetween the td tags