# Selecting a div in beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I can not select this div, in the attached images I show you how I tried to select it. the link in question is `https://www.tripadvisor.it/Hotels-g187898-Lucca_Province_of_Lucca_Tuscany-Hotels.html`

Any ideas?

https://ibb.co/bHxrff`1`
https://ibb.co/ecJ8RL`2`
https://ibb.co/cJuF6L`3`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: `soup.findAll('div',{'class':'price __resizeWatch'})`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: can you continue reading this post please?

Comment: it's very important for me

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow isn't for getting free developers to write your code.

It's right in the documentation

```
soup.find("div", class_="price __resizeWatch")
```

Comment: I apologize for my incomprehension

Comment: it's okay I was new a while back too. But please try to read documentation first, then searching your issue, and then as a last resort posting here.

Comment: i've already serching my issue but i've don't find a solution to solve it

Comment: I think you have to use class_ not class

Comment: I did not understand, can you please me to explain better?

Comment: To select class inside an HTML element you have to write class_ in beautifulsoup. This is to not confuse with pythons class objects