# Python Web Scraping - html parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to extract system status messages from nasdaq website. Here is the part of page source:

```
</script>
<h2>System Status Messages</h2>
<div id='divSSTAT'>
<div class="genTable">
<table style="width: 100%">
<colgroup>
<col class="gtcol1"></col>
<col class="gtcol2"></col>
<col class="gtcol3"></col>
</colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="gtcol1" style="width: 10%">Time</th>
<th class="gtcol2" style="width: 25%">Market</th>
<th class="gtcol3">Status</th>
</tr>
<tr class='sstatNone' ><td class="tddateWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;">11:56:46 ET</td><td class="tdmarketwidth">NASDAQ<br>BX<br>Post - Trade<br>PSX<br>NASDAQ Options<br>BX Options<br>PHLX<br>NASDAQ Futures<br>ISE<br>GEMX<br>MRX</td><td valign="top">Systems are operating normally</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Want the output like this:

```
System Status Messages
11:56:46 Systems are operating normally
```

Here is what i do to extract the page content:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=MarketSystemStatus"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.find_all(["h2","tr"])
```

This gives a lot of unwanted content. What's the best way to clean it,expecially the lines that contains the actual system message? right now it's like this...

```
<tr class='sstatNone' ><td class="tddateWidth" style="white-space: nowrap;">11:56:46 ET</td><td class="tdmarketwidth">NASDAQ<br>BX<br>Post - Trade<br>PSX<br>NASDAQ Options<br>BX Options<br>PHLX<br>NASDAQ Futures<br>ISE<br>GEMX<br>MRX</td><td valign="top">Systems are operating normally</td></tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class).

Comment: You need to search for the elements by their class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `td` tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = soup(content, 'html.parser')
_start, *_, _end = [i.text for i in s.find_all('td')]
results = f'{s.h2.text}\n{_start} {_end}'
print(results)
```

Output:

```
System Status Messages
11:56:46 ET Systems are operating normally
```

If you do not want `ET` included in the output, you can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
...
results = f'{s.h2.text}\n{re.sub(" [A-Z]+", "", _start)} {_end}'
```

Output:

```
System Status Messages
11:56:46 Systems are operating normally
```

Comment: This works nicely.thanks a lot! 
probably should be a separate thread, but do you know if there is a package to repeat the same task, for example, every 10 seconds, instead of writing a loop to do so?

Comment: @user10144318 Glad to help!

Comment: To repeat it every so often you can use crontab

Comment: @user10144318 It somewhat depends. If you wish to run the program in the console, a simple `while` loop with a `time.sleep` will suffice. However, if you wish to execute the program on a specific schedule, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373335/how-do-i-get-a-cron-like-scheduler-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

In the following you could split the 3 selector combinations into 3 individual select_one('indiv selector combination here') selections. Just showing for sake of interest combined.  Note that longer selectors and those using quantifiers are slightly less performant in css terms.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=MarketSystemStatus'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content,'lxml')
print(' '.join([item.text for item in soup.select('#content h2:nth-of-type(1), #divSSTAT .tddateWidth, #divSSTAT td:nth-of-type(3)')]))
```