# Is there a way to find class name and take the whole text of parent tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a lot of html files and I have to take the full header of files.
Tags of headers located differently: class="c6", class="c7"

I have tried BeautifulSoup

```
for head_c6 in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'c6'}):
        print(head_c6.get_text())
for head_c7 in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'c7'}):
        print(head_c7.get_text())
```

but the result:

Q3 2017 American Express Co Earnings Call - Final  **LENGTH:**

Q2 2016 Akamai Technologies Inc  Call - Final **Earnings**

Here how different files look like:

**File 1**

```
<div class="c4">
<p class="c5">
<span class="c6">
      Q3 2017 American Express Co Earnings Call - Final
     </span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="c4">
<p class="c5">
<span class="c7">
      LENGTH:
     </span>
<span class="c2">
      11051 words
     </span>
</p>
</div>
```

**File 2**

```
<div class="c4">
<p class="c5">
<span class="c6">
      Q2 2018 Akamai Technologies Inc
     </span>
<span class="c7">
      Earnings
     </span>
<span class="c6">
      Call - Final
     </span>
</p>
</div>
```

**File 3**

```
<div class="c4">
    <p class="c5">
     <span class="c6">
      Q4 2018
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Facebook
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Inc
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Earnings
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Call - Final
     </span>
    </p>
```

What I want is get full text of header:

**Q3 2017 American Express Co Earnings Call - Final**

**Q2 2018 Akamai Technologies Inc Earnings Call - Final**

**Q4 2018 Facebook Inc Earnings Call - Final**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: use findAll instead of find

Comment: I used find_all. And result in different order

Comment: Could you share the output.

Comment: @Siddharth Das I have edited, showing the result of find_all

Comment: I know you accepted an answer, but I'm still confused: the phrase "Earnings Call - Final" is in all outputs; assuming that's also the case in real life, why bother looking for it? Don't you really only need the name of the company and fiscal quarter?

Comment: I have shown only 3 companies. There are about 1500 companies and I have differential ends like "Earnings Conference Call - Final".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regular expression `re` I have updated the last file html.You can do it same with remaining files

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
data='''<div class="c4">
    <p class="c5">
     <span class="c6">
      Q4 2018
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Facebook
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Inc
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Earnings
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Call - Final
     </span>
    </p>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

items=[item.text.strip() for item in soup.find_all('span', class_=re.compile("c"))]
stritem=' '.join(items)
print(stritem.replace('\n',''))
```

Output:

```
 Q4 2018 Facebook Inc Earnings Call - Final
```

You can also use following way.

```
items=[item.text.strip() for item in soup.find_all('span', class_=re.compile("c6|c7"))]
stritem=' '.join(items)
print(stritem.replace('\n',''))
```

or to get the parent tag text try that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
data='''<div class="c4">
    <p class="c5">
     <span class="c6">
      Q4 2018
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Facebook
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Inc
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Earnings
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Call - Final
     </span>
    </p>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
childtag=soup.find('span', class_=re.compile("c6|c7"))
parenttag=childtag.parent
print(parenttag.text.replace('\n',''))
```

Comment: I have many c6 and c7 class tags in file. The first solution took everything and the second worked well on Facebook and Akamai Technologies but Q3 2017 American Express Co Earnings Call - Final LENGTH: LOAD-DATE: LANGUAGE:.  I do not need LENGTH: LOAD-DATE: LANGUAGE:

Answer (score 0):

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

[str.join(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) - Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html1 = ''' <div class="c4">
    <p class="c5">
     <span class="c6">
      Q4 2018
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Facebook
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Inc
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Earnings
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Call - Final
     </span>
    </p></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html1,'lxml')
tag =  soup.find('div',{'class':'c4'})
header = ' '.join(("".join((tag.text.strip()).split('\n'))).split())
print(header)
```

O/P

Q4 2018 Facebook Inc Earnings Call - Final

Answer (score 0):

It seems easier, and more efficient, to pass an Or list to select

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="c4">
    <p class="c5">
     <span class="c6">
      Q4 2018
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Facebook
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Inc
     </span>
     <span class="c7">
      Earnings
     </span>
     <span class="c6">
      Call - Final
     </span>
    </p>'''

soup= bs(html,'html.parser')  
result = ' '.join([item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('.c6,.c7')])
print(result)
```