# How can I use BeautifulSoup to get all IMDB user reviews of a movie

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I am working on a school project and want to get all user reviews of superhero movies of IMDB.

First, I try to get all user reviews of only 1 movie.

The page of user reviews, consists of 25 user reviews and a 'load more' button. While I already managed to write a code to open the load more button. I get stuck in the second part: getting all user reviews in a list.

I already tried to use BeautifulSoup to find all 'content' parts on the page. However, my list remains empty.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
testurl = "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0357277/reviews?ref_=tt_urv"
patience_time1 = 60
XPATH_loadmore = "//*[@id='load-more-trigger']"
XPATH_grade = "//*[@class='review-container']/div[1]"
list_grades = []

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(testurl)

# This is the part in which I open all 'load more' buttons.
while True:
    try:
        loadmore = driver.find_element_by_id("load-more-trigger")
        time.sleep(2)
        loadmore.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    print("Complete")
    time.sleep(10)

    # When the whole page is loaded, I want to get all 'content' parts.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    content = soup.findAll("content")
    list_content = [c.text_content() for c in content]

driver.quit()
```

I expect to get a list of all content of the review-containers on the website. However, my list remains empty.

Comment: Did you take a look at what requests happen when you click load more? It could be way easier to replicate the request instead.

Comment: i'm seeing `name 'webdriver' is not defined` when running your code locally. can you provide a `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @Jeff Xiao
I imported the following modules:
from selenium import webdriver   
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

Comment: @Marieke i've added an answer. another note is you may need to tweak the sleep time, currently it's unnecessarily long on my machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imdb+review

Comment: Try searchin on `[web-scraping] [beautifulsoup] infinite`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You use BeautifulSoup**4**, correct?

Method names changed from 3 to 4. ([document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names))

Also, `find_all` takes the *tag name*, and an optional `class_` param for the css class (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284921/3380951))

So your code should be using the new name:

```py
    # content = soup.findAll("content")
    content = soup.find_all('div', class_=['text','show-more__control'])
```

Also use `get_text()` in your list-comprehension:

```py
# list_content = [c.text_content() for c in content]
list_content = [tag.get_text() for tag in content]
```

Lastly, provide a parser when getting the soup: ([document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use))

```py
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="html.parser")
```

Otherwise you will encounter this UserWarning:

> SO56261323.py:36: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so
>   I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system
>   ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this
>   code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may
>   use a different parser and behave differently.