# Bs4 find p tags by class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make this code to scrape a website for product names. I am trying to find p tags with a specfic class.Here is the code, it justs prints out none when I run it. The element I am trying to scrape is commented.

```
#<p class="product-name">Yaesu FT-DX101D HF/50MHz 100W SDR</p>


import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.gigaparts.com/products/radios-amps-and-repeaters#/?Category1=Radios&Category2=Radios%2C+Amps+and+Repeaters&Category3=Radio+Transceivers&search_return=all&Category4=Base+Stations"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
for i in range(10):
    a_tags = soup.find("p", {"class": "product-name"})
    print(a_tags)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: If the purpose of the loop and `time.sleep` is to "wait" until all the elements will be visible, then it's not going to work. You only ever parse the response and build the `soup` object **once**. It's not ever going to change. If that page is loaded dynamically with JS then `BeautifulSoup` is not the correct tool. You will need to use `selenium`, `mechanize` or any other headless solution

Comment: Anyway, try to `print(response.text)` and search for the element. If it is not there, then the page is indeed dependant on JS and the other tools from my previous comment will need to be used

Answer (score 0):

You could mimic the jquery xhr but remove all the stuff that is superfluous and that look most likely to vary over time.

```
import requests, re, json, ast
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://gigaparts-v2.ecomm-nav.com/nav.js?initial_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gigaparts.com%2Fproducts%2Fradios-amps-and-repeaters%23%2F%3FCategory1%3DRadios%26Category2%3DRadios%252C%2BAmps%2Band%2BRepeaters%26Category3%3DRadio%2BTransceivers%26search_return%3Dall%26Category4%3DBase%2BStations&nxt_custom_options=formKey%3D%26groupId%3DNOT%2BLOGGED%2BIN&Category1=Radios&Category2=Radios%2C+Amps+and+Repeaters&Category3=Radio+Transceivers&search_return=all&Category4=Base+Stations&callback=jQuery0')
p = re.compile(r'jQuery0\((.*)\);')
d = ast.literal_eval(p.findall(r.text)[0])
soup = bs(d['content'], 'lxml')
product_names = [i.text for i in soup.select('.product-name')]
print(product_names )
```