# I want to scrape a website to track prices. How do I use soup.find() for class instead of id?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I usually use this code:

```
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
```

That's the Daraz website's code that I want to **scrape**:

```
<div class="pdp-product-title">
  <div class="pdp-mod-product-badge-wrapper">
    <img src="https://laz-img-cdn.alicdn.com/tfs/TB1rYuurhTpK1RjSZFMXXbG_VXa-205-48.png" class="pdp-mod-product-badge" alt="badge" />
    <span class="pdp-mod-product-badge-title">Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro [4 GB RAM, 64 GB ROM ] 6.3 Inches Screen</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider beautifying your code

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try? just one line it is not a code... SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```py
soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

taken directly from [the bs4 docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

You may also see here: [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class).