# How should I scrape the text of website which is represented by 1 of the 'p' tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm a newbie at Python, and am practicing web scraping by extracting data from a [news website](https://www.npr.org/2019/12/29/792241464/civil-rights-leader-rep-john-lewis-to-start-treatment-for-pancreatic-cancer).

I currently face 2 problems:

1. How do I scrape the text, which is represented by a

   tag? It
   is one of many on the web page. For e.g. the first one is just before 
   the author's name.
2. The CSV file I exported only contains the headers, but no text. Why? How
   do I fix this?

Here's the code, many thanks for your help.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas import DataFrame
import csv
import re

f = open ('nprtest1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
writer.writerow ('headline', 'date', 'author', 'body' )

*#set the page you want to visit*
url="https://www.npr.org/2019/12/29/792241464/civil-rights-leader-rep-john-lewis-to-start-treatment-for-pancreatic-cancer"
#request page using the request library
page=requests.get(url)


#create soup - parse HTML of webpage
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

headline=soup.find("h1").text
date=soup.find("time").text
body = soup.find_all('p')


### regex to remove tags and other irrelevant bits
date_final = re.sub("\n","",date)

webdata = [headline, date_final, body]

writer.writerow (webdata)
df = pd.read_csv('webscraping_test1.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the specific text that you want, you can find the element by class. You can find more about that in this answer: [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

For the csv problem, since you are already using pandas, I think you'll be better off using panda's [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function.