# Python, trying to parse strange things

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse content from specific website for example https://temp-mail.org/en i want parse Email address, am not familiar with java or what is this idk. Please Help how can i do this? what i have done it only parse content but in content i cant find field with email address. Can u explain what is this

```
<input class="emailbox-input opentip disabledText" data-original-title="Your Temporary Email Address" data-placement="bottom" data-value="Loading" id="mail" onclick="select(this);" readonly="" type="text"/>
```

i using this code:

```
>>>page = requests.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/')
>>>soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
>>>soup
```

Now i tried with silenium if i am right, but no output...

```
>>>driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
>>>driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/')
>>> elemts = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='mail')
>>> elemts
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4bfd1e55807ce38331d70d93b3e9ff94", element="64def6cd-5c1a-4bf0-bf7e-0419718ac256")>
>>>elemts.text
''
```

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: `soup.find(_class = 'emailbox-input')` will get the field. But this is an input field that the user fills in when they go to the site, it won't have any useful information when you scrape it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class

Comment: @Barmar it not users fills this, it fills automatically

Comment: @n1rna nope it not

Comment: @robotiaga have you looked at the selenium documentation?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle can u be more specific? i cant read all documentation in 10 min :D

Comment: Yeah i mean had you done any research on how to read the value of an input field. I have added an answer showing this based on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value of the email address thats prepopulated by the javascript then just get the value of the input field.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/')
elemts = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='mail')
print("Email address:", elemts.get_attribute('value'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Email address: kokida8790@etcone.net
```