# How do I extract all the links of a certain section of a web page with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract only the links of a certain section in a webpage but all the tutorials I find on Beautifulsoup always scrape the whole page.

How do I scrape only the links within a certain `<div class="xyz">`???

EDIT:
I currently have this code:

```
soup1.find_all('h3', class_="entry-title td-module-title")
```

This finds all the links of the webpage, which are contained in the `class_="entry-title td-module-title"`

I want to find all the links that are still contained in the class

```
"entry-title td-module-title"`
```

But only those contained in the section represented by:

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
```

(Sorry if my question was a bit lacking of information, I tried to add more details)

Comment: `soup.findAll("div", {"class": "xyz"})` This should work. Later you should scrape the individual links inside the section by storing this in a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
soup2 =  soup1.find_all('div',class_='wpb_wrapper')
results = []
for div in soup2:
    required = div.find_all('h3', class_="entry-title td-module-title")
    results.append(required)
```

Comment: I solved it in a different way, but your answer was still very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector for this task:

```
for link in soup.select('div.wpb_wrapper h3.entry-title.td-module-title a'):
    print(link['href'])
```

This will print all links that are under `<h3 class="entry-title td-module-title">` which is under `<div class="wpb_wrapper">`.