# beautifulsoup how to extract text from a specific class

Tags: python, html, class, beautifulsoup

I want to print a text from div that has this class="enrte_text_itempo" Can i print it just by typing this or someithng like this?

```
for div in soup.find_all("div", { class = "enrte_text_itempo"}):
    print(div.get_text())
```

because i get an error that says invalid syntax and points my word:class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Comment: ``soup.find_all("div", {"clas" : "enrte_text_itempo"})``

Comment: @sushanth oh its {"class" : "..."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the correct syntax:

```
desired_divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "enrte_text_itempo"})
```

OR

You could search by the [`class_`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) keyword:

```
desired_divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="enrte_text_itempo")
for div in desried_divs:
    print(div)
```

Comment: i fixed it, it needed " " and : instead of =