# BeautifulSoup4 error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Problem:** So, I wanted to get links from a search results on a wiki from a game, and got this error

**Link from search resutls im trying to get to:** [Html.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MItBM.png)

**Error:** `li_tag = ul_tag.find('li') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find`

**Code:**

```
    ul_tag = h2_tag.find('ul')
    li_tag = ul_tag.find('li')
    div_tag = li_tag.find('div')
    a_tag = div_tag.find('a')

    urls.append(a_tag.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: One of your finds is not returning a result. The error message will contain a stacktrace which will point to which line and therefore which `find` is failing.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class. This should allow you to quickly find all elements using `mw-redirect` class

Comment: So, the problem was that the ul tag wasn't inside the h2 tag, but now I the program can't find the a tag inside the div, and by the screenshot I posted with the question, there should be one inside it, right? @AlastairMcCormack (just saw your second comment, I'll try that too)

Comment: Remember that you're looking at the DOM, not the source code. Any Javascript on the page can add new entries to the DOM. BS only reads the source code. Check the source code contains the information you're looking for. Also consider my previous point about searching for the class or classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `h2_tag.find('ul')` **not found anything** so it returns `None`. *h2* tag is not including *ul* and *li*, *h2* tag opened and closed. Try searching XML and see some examples that will help you so much.