# Extracting nested span / p / div structure using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract this part from a page:

[image]

Using the inspect I see that:

[image]

**Is the structure defined in the inspect view always follows what `bs4` returns?**

I am using:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSWVk1yd_I_zhVROYN2wv1r1y_54M-QL0199ZQ4g9mQZ7QdzekVzsRFUB_JVfkInwLxDNPmrwlY2x7y/pub?fbclid=IwAR0BsTNrbDeLb6j7tU2XhVxeh9WaQU_vELyDS3oNvem3eapiJ1zoBqZIYes"    
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")  
data = soup.find_all('span',"c2")
```

But it returns:

```
[<span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2">Gyventojai, kuriems yra daugiau nei 65 metai (1.14 prioritetas)</span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2">——————————————————————</span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2">Švietimo sistemos darbuotojai bei abiturientai (1.15 prioritetas)</span>,
 <span class="c2">Diplomatai (1.16)</span>,
 <span class="c2">Sergantieji lėtinėmis ligomis (1.17)</span>,
 <span class="c2">Socialinių paslaugų teikėjai (1.18)</span>,
 <span class="c2">1.20 prioritetas: gyvybiškai svarbias valstybės funkcijas atliekantys asmenys, kontaktuojantys su kitais asmenimis (pareigūnai, prekybos įmonių salės darbuotojai ir kt.), išskyrus bendrųjų funkcijų darbuotojus. Šiuo metu šio prioriteto sąrašai nuolat keliami.</span>,
 <span class="c2">Gyventojų grupė 55-64 m.</span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2">.</span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>,
 <span class="c2"></span>]
```

Which does not include `<p class="c6"><span class="c2">ŠIUO METU - TIK SENJORAI:</span></p>`

And I am unsure why because it clearly states `class c2` in both inspect view and the `data` returned by `bs4`.

**Should I always follow the nested structure with multiple `find` statements or what is the best practice to get the data I desire?**

Comment: Regarding the selection of certain elements by class name via bs4, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22284921/13044314)

Comment: It does not return what you say.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, probably, because as Andrej said, the classes keep changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, the CSS class name changes every reload, so sometimes is `c7`, on reload is `c1` and so on.

This example will search for CSS class name that contains "red" color (as your desired text is) and then uses this class name to find your text:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSWVk1yd_I_zhVROYN2wv1r1y_54M-QL0199ZQ4g9mQZ7QdzekVzsRFUB_JVfkInwLxDNPmrwlY2x7y/pub?fbclid=IwAR0BsTNrbDeLb6j7tU2XhVxeh9WaQU_vELyDS3oNvem3eapiJ1zoBqZIYes"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text

# find CSS class name that is red:
class_name = re.search(r"\.(c\d+)\{color:#cc0000;", html_doc).group(1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

print(soup.find(class_=class_name).text)
```

Prints:

```
ŠIUO METU - TIK SENJORAI:
```

Comment: Thank you. Why does the classes keep changing?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis That I don't know (maybe Google keeps various versions of the document on its servers?)