# How can I find a specific div tag using bs4

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an html text and find all the "<div class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant">" tags.

```
warpips = open('WarpipsPageText.txt', 'r')
page_text = warpips.read()
warpips.close()
bs4 = BeautifulSoup(page_text, 'html5lib')
div = bs4.find_all('div class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant"', bs4)
print(div)
```

When I run this code it prints an empty list.

Below is a snippet from the html of what I am trying to isolate.

```
        <div class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant">
            CDKeys.com
                                                <div class="platform platform-pc" title="pc"></div>
                                                                <div class="platform platform-xbox" title="xbox"></div>
                                    </div>
    </div>
    <span class="topclick-list-element-price">$11.19</span>
 </a>
                                                                                                 <a href="https://cheapdigitaldownload.com/nier-replicant-ver-1-22474487139-digital-download-price-comparison/" title="NieR Replicant ver.1.22474487139 cd key best prices" class="topclick-list-element ">
    <div class="topclick__image tpsprite11 tpsprite11-82-buy-nier-replicant-ver-1-22474487139-cd-key-pc-download-catalog-0" data-tp="tpsprite11"></div>
    <div class="topclick-list-element-game">
        <div class="topclick-list-element-game-title">NieR Replicant ver.1.22474487139</div>
        <div class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find elements by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class)

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced a single quote.

```
div = bs4.find_all('div', class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant")
```

Comment: That gives me this error:
`div = bs4.find_all('div', class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant")`
                              
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `div = bs4.find_all('div', {"class": "topclick-list-element-game-merchant"})`

Answer (score 0):

To find all `<div>` with `class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant"` you can use following example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
        <div class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant">
            CDKeys.com
                                                <div class="platform platform-pc" title="pc"></div>
                                                                <div class="platform platform-xbox" title="xbox"></div>
                                    </div>
    </div>
    <span class="topclick-list-element-price">$11.19</span>
 </a>
                                                                                                 <a href="https://cheapdigitaldownload.com/nier-replicant-ver-1-22474487139-digital-download-price-comparison/" title="NieR Replicant ver.1.22474487139 cd key best prices" class="topclick-list-element ">
    <div class="topclick__image tpsprite11 tpsprite11-82-buy-nier-replicant-ver-1-22474487139-cd-key-pc-download-catalog-0" data-tp="tpsprite11"></div>
    <div class="topclick-list-element-game">
        <div class="topclick-list-element-game-title">NieR Replicant ver.1.22474487139</div>
        <div class="topclick-list-element-game-merchant">
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for div in soup.find_all(class_="topclick-list-element-game-merchant"):
    print(div.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
CDKeys.com
```