# Find the H-tags inside a class with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a bit of a problem counting all H-tags in an article I need to keep the search inside the main article class-part of the code. It looks something like this.

```
<article class="Article-p6ncbx-0 hxYamq">
 <div class ="">
  <div class ="">
   <div class ="">
    <div class ="">
     <div class ="">
      <div class ="">
       <h3>I need to search this one</h3>
      </div> 
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</article>
<footer class="Footer-238971asd sdjkYsd">
 <div class ="">
  <div class ="">
   <div class ="">
    <div class ="">
     <h3>But I dont want to find this H3-tag</h3>
```

Running this code will show all H1 to H4 tags on the page, also counting the header and footer, which both are outside the article class.

```
for heading in soup.find_all(["h1", "h2", "h3","h4"]):
   print(heading.name + ' ' + heading.text.strip())
```

I'm new to this and have a hard time understand how I can keep the search inside the article class. Any help would be very appreciated.

I understand this topic has been covered in length before, but I can't find a solution to this specific issue where I need to keep inside the class. Feel free to correct me if this could be solved by a simple search.

Here is a screenshot of how the entire thing looks. [Here is the actual page also](https://www.prisjakt.nu/sa-valjer-du-ratt-grill--ecXqqVohAAACIARDWF).

[The page html/css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgBwZ.jpg)

Comment: does the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class) help you ?

Comment: Is the end tag `</article >` before the tag `<footer>`?

Comment: You could start by searching for the *article* tag then search for h1/2/3 tags as children of the *article*

Comment: Could you exactly post how the HTML looks like. It is not clear if ```<footer>``` is inside ```<article>``` or outside.

Comment: Thank you all for input. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count / print only the headings from the articles - first select all `<article>` from soup and second `find_all()` headings in selection:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get('https://www.prisjakt.nu/sa-valjer-du-ratt-grill--ecXqqVohAAACIARDWF')

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

for article in soup.select('article'):
    for heading in article.find_all(['h1', 'h2', 'h3','h4']):
        print(heading.name + ' ' + heading.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
h1 Så väljer du rätt grill
h4 Kolgrill, gasolgrill, elgrill – vad ska man egentligen välja? Här får du tipsen och råden du behöver innan du väljer!
h3 Kolgrillen
h4 Fördelar
h4 Nackdelar
h4 3 populäraste kolgrillarna våren 2021
h3 Grillkol eller briketter?
h3 Gasolgrillen
h4 3 populäraste gasolgrillarna våren 2021
h3 Elgrillen
h4 3 populäraste elgrillarna våren 2021
h3 Prisjakts grilltips
```

Instead of `text.strip()` you can also use `get_text(strip=True)`
`

Comment: Thank you HedgeHog. I realize the answer was super easy, but I needed to see it like this to get it into my head. Thanks again and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your `soup.find_all` call to a `soup` object anchored on an `article` selection. Additionally, since `h` tags range from 1 to 6, you can pass an `re.compile` object to `find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
results = soup.select_one('article').find_all(re.compile('h\d+'))
```