# couldn't find the element by soup.find

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, find

I couldn't find the value. the value location in html is  (span 161 /span)
Should I try xpath method to get theelement ? Or better suggetion ?

```
!pip install Selenium
from selenium import webdriver

# 要把chromedriver 放在同一層資料夾裡
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://shopee.tw/shop/10228173/search?page=0&sortBy=ctime")
source = browser.page_source

import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
browser.get("https://www.rakuten.com.tw/shop/watsons/product/956957/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
soup
products =[]
product = {}
#     product['網址'] = link

product['購買次數'] = soup.find('div',class_="b-container-child").span
products.append(product)
print(products)
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: If your idea is to find the items by class name you can refer to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class

Comment: output 
'購買次數': <span class="b-sprite-label-point">樂天點數</span>}]

But the value isn't what I need.  I need the value : 161 in the page. How could I use the corecct code to get the value ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `headers` to get full data from `soup` and also you have to select which element you have to find so from `b-container-child` we have to select `2nd` index and from it we have to find last `span` tag and then it will return `161` as output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://www.rakuten.com.tw/shop/watsons/product/956957/",headers=headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
all_data=soup.find_all("div",class_="b-container-child")[2]
main_data=all_data.find_all("span")[-1]
print(main_data.text)
```

Output:

```
161
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see if I use span to get all data, then  pick up the correct value step by step, I can get that. It's really helpful !